# '' is a Namespace but used as a Type

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, google-geocoder

I have searched through many similar questions to this, none have had the answer for my own issues..  In an ASP.Net MVC application I have 2 projects, an ASP.NET Web Application (.Net Framework) and a Class library.
In a Controller in the Web App I am trying to instantiate an object of one of the classes in the Class library, however, I get the error that is the title of the post.

This is the constructor part of the class I am trying to access..

```
namespace GoogleDirections
{
    public sealed class Geocoder : HttpWebService
    {
        public Geocoder(string key) : base(key)
        {
        }
}
```

And this is the call in the controller..

```
public double[] GetLatLong(string address)
{
    double[] latLng = new double[2];
    var geocoder = new Geocoder("xxxMyAPIKeyblahblahxx");
    return latLng;
}
```

The error is "'Geocoder' is a Namespace but used as a Type"

The controller has using statement `using GoogleDirections; and references the Class library that contains the Geocoder class.`

Does anyone have a clue what I might have been missing?

Comment: you realize you are missing a closing bracket for your class. fix that first

Comment: try writing `new GoogleDirections.Geocoder("YourKey") ` Or in which namespace that Geocoder class is

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary this shouldn't even compile though, right?

Comment: So, on a new line, type `Geocoder` and then a `.`. See what pops up. Is any of it familiar?

Comment: Can you show namespace of the controller you're using? Possibly you have another namespace with name `Geocoder` somewhere, causing confusion between namespace and class constructor.

Comment: Related article by Eric Lippert [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/03/09/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one/). Avoid reusing same name already used in namespace as class name, type name etc.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary the closing bracket is in the program, I just missed it when I copied this over to here.

Comment: @TobiasBrohl that did the trick, thanks

Answer (score 1):

As written in the commemts, 
try writing `new GoogleDirections.Geocoder("YourKey")` Or in which namespace that Geocoder class is, but here it can be marked as answer.